# PHP unserialize function get any number from 0-9

Tags: php, function, serialization, numbers

I need to get product id with the unserialize php funcion. I have this text

```
a:1:{i:4;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"209";s:5:"price";d:1;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:12:"product_name";s:4:"test";s:11:"thumb_image";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}}
```

and I get the product_id with this PHP code:

```
$rslt = unserialize($data);
echo $rslt[4]["product_id"]);
```

So my question is there a way to do something like `echo $rslt[x]["product_id"];`where x is any number between 0-9

Also tried this but doesn't work

```
        $i=0;
        while($rslt[$i]["product_id"]!="")
            {
            echo $i;
            //echo $rslt[4]["product_id"];                    
            echo $rslt[$i]["product_id"];
            $i++;
            }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you did?

Comment: @ExplosionPills there is nothing wrong, but the number in $rslt[4]- the number between the brackets is the number from the text after {i: that is 4, but not always is 4. It can be any number between 0-9

Comment: try `echo $rslt[mt_rand(0, 9)]["product_id"];`

Comment: a:1:{i:4;a:17:{s:..... you only have array(4 => array(... in your serialization, only $rslt[4]["product_id"] will be defined

Comment: According to JSONLint - your JSON isn't VALID JSON.

Comment: His JSON is not JSON and never claimed to be so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you unserialize your input you have a good old PHP array, equivalent to:

```
$rslt = array (
  4 => 
  array (
    'quantity' => 1,
    'product_id' => 5196,
    'category_id' => '209',
    'price' => 1,
    'tax' => '18.00',
    'tax_id' => '1',
    'description' => '',
    'product_name' => 'test',
    'thumb_image' => '',
    'ean' => '',
    'attributes' => 'a:0:{}',
    'attributes_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'weight' => '0.0000',
    'vendor_id' => '0',
    'files' => 'a:0:{}',
    'freeattributes' => 'a:0:{}',
    'dependent_attr_serrialize' => 'a:0:{}',
  ),
);
```

To grab the first element, just call [current()](http://php.net/current) as with any other array:

```
$first_item = current($rslt);
print_r($first_item['product_id']);
```